# Highcharts, how to put markers on min/max values on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart graph with xAxis being datetime, on yAxis i have different datas. One is the temperature.
I would like to put markers on the Min and Min values for each day, like this :[image]
How can i do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add flags to show min max values. I am using flags with highstock js. On `load` event I am finding min and max values and add series of type `flags`.

```
this.addSeries({
            type: 'flags',
            data: [{
              x: newArr[maxIndex].x,
              y: newArr[maxIndex].y,
              title: 'Max:'+newArr[maxIndex].y,
            },{
              x: newArr[minIndex].x,
              y: newArr[minIndex].y,
              title: 'Min: '+newArr[minIndex].y,
            }],

          });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw5c037v/) demo

Comment: Hi Deep 3015,
Thanks for your answer. So it seems to be possible... :-)
I'm not sure if i can understand your script and adapt it to mine..
I'm not a big JS programmer...
I already have a function to display sunrise and sunset plotbands, so don't know if a can have another function ?
thanks a lot !

Comment: Try to use only `load` function logic from my example. I am using date wise plot band, yours is sun based plot band. Add live example, I will try to resolve

Comment: Hi, i never made a fiddle..
But i forked yours, cleaned it and added my function .
See if it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/t7cvj6w2/

Comment: Great !
I managed to find a way to display the firebug console. What is this #15 error ?
I will see if i can include this on my page and get ride of the series # display and adapt the flags . i want only a dot .
Thanks a lot !

Comment: you can try with options given here  https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.shape